# Can chemicals soak into a steel sink and cause health issues?

Tags: drain, kitchen-sink, chemicals

I wonder…I have a 20 years old stainless kitchen sink in good condition.

Somebody poured [Green Gobbler](https://greengobbler.com/products/dissolve-liquid-hair-clog-remover) into the sink. Green Gobbler is a drain clog dissolver (supposed to be kitchen sink safe and non-caustic but who knows).

I cleaned the sink with hot water and soap. Can residual of the Green Gobbler be absorbed into the stainless steel and be hazardous, i.e. “poison” the sink?

Thank you

Comment: In general, stainless steel is least vulnerable to chemical problems of the common sink materials. Stone, whether real or manufactured (Corian, etc.), porcelain (to a lesser degree), etc. are all, IMHO, far more likely to end up with some sort of stain/permanent damage than stainless steel, with the exception of something corrosive enough to damage the steel very quickly on contact - which would be quite noticeable if it happened.

Comment: According to the safety data sheet on the website,there are absolutely no hazardous ingredients in that product. Thus even if it somehow absorbed into the sink (which it won't),it still wouldn't pose a risk. It's likely a mixture of enzymes,so at worst you'd just consume a bit of extra protein.

Comment: Honestly, you've got a clog remover product that is _designed to be poured into sinks_ to dissolve clogs. If it was going to "poison" the sink, do you think it would be sold? Wouldn't it come with warnings to _not_ use it on a stainless steel sink (or some other type of material) if it were dangerous to do so?  The bottle says "Proudly made in the USA". There are so many bloody stupid lawsuits in the US, that there would be all _kinds_ of warnings on the package if it were going to "poison" the sink...

Comment: Sink licking, @crip659, would only be a problem if the sink wasn't given a thorough rinsing after using the clog remover. Don't dip a glass in it for a drink while it's working, but once it's thoroughly rinsed (with just plain water), there shouldn't be a trace.

Comment: yes, normal "end of dishwashing" sink-cleaning efforts with soap and scrubbie should positively remove any remaining material.

Answer (score 6):

Former chemist here. Stainless steel is great! Not much can eat through it, and we love it almost as much as glass. Based on that alone I'd be comfortable saying a consumer cleaner is unlikely to do much to it at all. Even the stuff we kept around in the lab wouldn't touch it, I'd have to do some bench top synthesis if I wanted to give stainless a bad day.

Digging a little deeper, the page you referenced has a link to the SDS (Safety Data Sheet) for Green Gobbler, which I read through. This is not a notably reactive chemical in any sense of the word. The worst line in this data sheet is 'may cause eye and skin irritation', which is a boilerplate warning we put on data sheets for literally every material other than water.

So: don't drink it, don't bathe in it, and don't worry about what it'll do to your sink.

Answer (score 3):

No. According to the website you cited in your question it will not "poison" your sink.

Scrub the sink good and rinse it down the drain.

Answer (score 3):

Stainless steel does not absorb anything, except hydrogen under certain conditions.

Comment: Even when its older 10-20 years old stainless steel?

Comment: yes.,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: @Mike3657 Yeah, the whole point of stainless is it's chemically stable and doesn't change.